# Default substituting %s in python scripts

Tags: python, string, substitution

Sometimes in Python scripts I see lines like:

```
cmd = "%s/%s_tb -cm cond+line+fsm -ucli -do \"%s\""
```

Where is the `%s` in the above line substituted? Does Python have some stack of strings and it pops them and replaces `%s`?

Comment: "DOes python has some stack of strings and it pops them and replaces %s?"  No.  You need to find a line that has `cmd %` on it.  Include that in your question too, please.

Answer (score 22):

**Basics of python string formatting**

Not a specific answer to your line of code, but since you said you're new to python I thought I'd use this as an example to share some joy ;)

Simple Example Inline With a List:

```
>>> print '%s %s %s'%('python','is','fun')
python is fun
```

Simple Example Using a Dictionary:

```
>>> print '%(language)s has %(number)03d quote types.' % \  
...       {"language": "Python", "number": 2}
Python has 002 quote types
```

When in doubt, check the python official docs - http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: Er. Does this answer his question? He wants to know how it's possible to have a string with `%s` in it without also specifying the replacements at the same time

Comment: Not directly, I was more addressing his statement of being new to Python. Sometimes a little bit of information about WHY something works the way it does can be helpful! Cheers.

Comment: There is a mistake in your script. Remove the is from the print or from the arguments. Now it would output: 'python is is fun'.

Comment: It answered my question. I thought the variable values has to be specified right there like perl. But this is different. In my script they have something like this at a different line, which i have not noticed.
cmd = cmd % (self.agent.tmp_dir, arch_id,
                     "%s.do" % self.agent.get_script(test.get_name()))

Thank you so much for your answers. I got 3 answers in less than 5 minutes. Thank you so much

Answer (score 21):

That would be later used in something like:

```
print cmd % ('foo','boo','bar')
```

What you're seeing is just a string assignment with fields in it which will later be filled in.

Comment: OK Thanks! Thats exactly what is happening. It is filled later in an another line. I am good at PERL and so i thought it has to be filled there. Thanks so much for answer

Answer (score 20):

It's being used for string interpolation. The `%s` is replaced by a string. You use the modulo operator (`%`) to do string interpolation. The string will be on the left side, the values to substitute for the various `%s` are on the right, in a tuple.

```
>>> s = '%s and %s'

>>> s % ('cats', 'dogs' )
<<< 'cats and dogs'
```

If you have just a single character you can forget the tuple.

```
>>> s = '%s!!!'

>>> s % 'what'
<<< 'what!!!'
```

In newer versions of python the recommend way is to use the `format` method of the string type:

```
>>> '{0} {1}'.format('Hey', 'Hey')
<<< 'Hey Hey'
```